# Where can I find the pygame.image class?

Tags: python, pygame

I would like to edit the pygame.image to add a method that returns the name of the object.

I've been looking around in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` where I found Pygame, but I can't find the image class, even though I have found the folder.

Anyone knows?

Comment: The filename? It would be easier to write a class that contains or subclasses `pygame.sprite.Sprite()` that remembers the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If related to SDL wrapper from https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-sdl2/downloads then see: SDL../sdl2/ext folder has the image.py

Assuming you want the pre-compiled C version, see the pygame/src has a image.c and image.doc (documentation).

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pygame 1.9.1 release, it's in the src folder, but is implemented in C.